# Setting a Tablistener method for tabs in action bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I'm trying to modify a [tutorial](http://www.lucazanini.eu/2012/android/tab-layout-in-android-with-actionbar-and-fragment/?lang=en), about swipes and tabs, so I can manually set the Tablistener method for each tab, which I insert into the action bar. The reason for this is, I want to be able to edit each Fragment file seperately (now they are created dynamically).

The code from the tutorial for dynamically setting the Tablistener for a specific tab:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mCollectionPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
         .setText(mCollectionPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
         .setTabListener(this)); //this is of type FragmentActivity
}
```

I want to change this by manually specifying the Tablistener for every tab. Example:

```
Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
tab.setText("tabName");
tab.setTabListener(new TabListener<Tab1Fragment>(this, "tabName", Tab1Fragment.class));
// the first parameter should be an Activity object, but mine is a FragmentActivity
actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

When I try the above code I get two errors:

- the type ActionBar.TabListener is not generic; it cannot be parametrized with arguments        <Tab1Fragment>
- Cannot instantiate the type ActionBar.Tablistener

What could be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to put these two imports on the top of your java file (after package definition):

import android.app.ActionBar;

import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;

It worked for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the official documentation, [ActionBar.TabListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html) is an interface so you must implement it.

Comment: The interface was already implemented (as you can see in the tutorial). I would only like to change the code, which I pasted above.

Comment: yes, but the interface is only implemented by this. What I understood is that you want to create custom implementation for each tab (or fragment). Then you should have more than one implementation